# Drag and Drop a .PNG image overtop another one in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag

I have a HTML page that contains 2 tables, each table has 6 rows and each row holds 6 (90px by 90px) image. All images are .PNG and ideally I want to be able to drag one image, and have it drop into the other table and overlay the other image.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="play-area">
        <table class="piecetray">
            <tr>
                <td><img src="media/hex1.png"></td>
                <td><img src="media/hrt1.png"></td>
                <td><img src="media/pent1.png"></td>
                <td><img src="media/up1.png"></td>
                <td><img src="media/tri1.png"></td>
                <td><img src="media/star1.png"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="media/star1.png"></td>
                <td><img src="media/tri1.png"></td>
                <td><img src="media/up1.png"></td>
                <td><img src="media/pent1.png"></td>
                <td><img src="media/hrt1.png"></td>
                <td><img src="media/hex1.png"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="media/hex1.png"></td>
                <td><img src="media/hrt1.png"></td>
                <td><img src="media/pent1.png"></td>
                <td><img src="media/up1.png"></td>
                <td><img src="media/tri1.png"></td>
                <td><img src="media/star1.png"></t
```

and the CSS for the tables...

```
    .gametray {
    background-color: black;
    border: 3px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.gametray td {
    background-color: #003399;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.gametray img { 
    display: block;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
}

.piecetray {
    background-color: #0052CC;
    border: 3px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.piecetray td {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.piecetray img {
    display: block;
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
}
```

In JavaScript I have pulled all the images in as follows:

```
Perfection.view = {
timer       :   currentTime = document.getElementById("timer"),
**dragPieces    :   document.querySelectorAll(".piecetray td img"),
**targetPieces  :   document.querySelectorAll(".gametray td img"),
updateTime  :   function(count) {
                    this.timer.innerHTML = count;
                }
```

I have played around with creating functions to handle the:
allowDrop (preventDefault())
Handle drag event and Handle drop event.

The code I am using isn't working. In the web console there are no errors. I was using a function something like 
`function handleDrop(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var piece = event.dataTransfer.getData("text", event.target);`

There was also a line in the code to appendChild. The reason I have not posted the actual code yet is because I have posted this from my phone.

I set up my event handlers to test one of the images by doing something like

Perfection.view.dragPieces[1].ondrop = handleDrop;

The closest I got was that the piece image I was testing on would drag and when I drop, it would disappear from the original location, and a random location (square) on the destination table would turn black, unfortunately that's not what I'm going for

Can anyone help me?

Cheers

Comment: Please edit your question to describe *how* your code isn't working. If you're getting an error message, add the error message. If you're getting incorrect behavior, please describe the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by adding a class when the drop event occurs and then set the properties of the td elements and the new .matched class to allow image overlay using z-index....like this...

```
function handleDrop(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var piece = document.querySelector(".selected");
var target = event.target;
var targetParent = event.target.parentElement; //this gets the td element
    if (getName(piece) === getName(target)) {
        targetParent.appendChild(piece);
        piece.classList.remove("selected");
        piece.classList.add("matched"); //this class gets added
    }
```

}

And the CSS for the td elements and the new class:

```
.gametray td {
    position: relative;
}

table td .matched {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
}
```